# Is there anyway to hide a menu/title on a web page and have the text appear automatically after x amount of seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have an idea for my school project, and I've been searching online how to add this feature in css or java. I just want the title and whole menu to be hidden for around 5 or 6 seconds before appearing on the webpage. I was thinking of using a div to hide these, but I'm not 100% sure if that would work with a menu because of all of its content and links. Any advice or help is appreciated!

Comment: Yes it is possible however without seeing what you got, it's hard to say exactly what you need to do. Basically you hide the title and menu by default with css, then you can show them using js

Comment: you can even use css3 animation and transition to trigger visibility after desired seconds

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pure CSS example:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XMYaL/1)

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="show-after-five">
         <h1>Hey! I am here 5 seconds late</h1>
    </div>
</div>


.show-after-five {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-name: fade-in;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-duration: 0.3s;
    animation-delay: 3s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -webkit-animation-name: fade-in;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinte;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes fade-in {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fade-in {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

create a div with `display:none` style attribute, and put all your menu stuff in there that you want to hide:

```
<div id="mydiv" style="display:none">
...
</div>
```

then using jQuery on the bottom of your page:

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#mydiv').fadeIn();
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

This will execute the show method in 5000 milliseconds, or 5 seconds, and will have a nice fade in effect. This is all just based on what you described you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite easy to do using Javascript (in particular, jQuery).

Place your menu on the DOM:

```
<div class="menu">Pretend this is a menu</div>
```

Set its display to `none` on page load:

```
.menu {
    display: none;
}
```

Then set a timer when the document is ready to make it appear after 5 seconds:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function (event) {
        $('.menu').show();
    }, 5000);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3Grdd/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. And there are many ways to do so. Easiest would be jQuery mixed with CSS3.

CSS:

`#target_ID{
display: none;
}`

jQuery:

`$(function() {
 $("#target_id").delay(6000).show();
 });`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery delay() function to accomplish this.

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#menu').delay(500).removeClass('.hidden');
});
```

Instead of removeClass() you can use fadeIn() or any other jQuery transition function.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the other answers suggest using display:none. I would be cautious because that will remove that content from the layout and potentially mess things up depending on how you have the site coded. If you have Jquery loaded, [here is a way to do it](http://codepen.io/tazcarper/pen/CFLbd).

CSS

```
.menu {opacity:0;}
.title {opacity:0;}
```

Javscript

```
setTimeout( function(){
$('.menu , .title').animate({ opacity:1 },3000);
}, 3000);
```

".menu" and ".title" are your containers. The first '3000' is the animation time of the fade in. The second '3000' is the delay. 3000 = 3 seconds. 5000 = 5 seconds, ect...